# Pass on query param to next page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, java-web-start

```
<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/order.htm"/>
    <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>         
</beans:bean>
```

Hi, i have a success handler like above.
When the user lands on login page with query param, i need to retain the query param on post login pages. how can i achieve that? 
I managed to see the request params in `successfulAuthentication` method which authenticates the user. the only challenge is how to pass on the same query params to next page
some thing like below? or any other better way?

```
<beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/order.htm?paramTest=pp1"/>
```

**Edit** SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler has the capability to retain the previous url(here url with query param in this case), but i have defaultTargetUrl set to new url, which is why its not effective. 
any possibilities to build the new defaultTargetUrl with query params from the previous login page?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to override SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler to achieve the same

```
public class CustomSavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private final Logger logger = ResmedLogger.getInstance().getTraceLogger();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session != null) {
        String paramTest = (String) session.getAttribute("paramTest");
        logger.info("paramTest="+paramTest);
        if (paramTest != null) {
            // we do not forget to clean this attribute from session
            session.removeAttribute("paramTest");
            // then we redirect
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/order.htm?paramTest="+paramTest);
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    } else {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

}